# Error while creating Event Receiver

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sandbox-solution, event-receivers, feature-receiver

This is Sample of my Code

```
SPList list = new SPSite(siteURL).OpenWeb().Lists[listName];
SPEventReceiverDefinitionCollection eventReceivers = list.EventReceivers;

SPEventReceiverDefinition eventReceiver = eventReceivers.Add();
```

but when i use this code it returns error while Build Project and error is

> Error 1   'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventReceiverDefinitionCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventReceiverDefinitionCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What Should I do now? can anybody help me Its Urgent.. Its a Sandboxed Solution..

Comment: I m facing same problem.. will you please tell how did you get solve this in your case? I m trying to add event receiver in Feature activating code. Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: I just changed my project from Sandboxed to Farm.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need to keep my solution Sandbox only  , as i need to use that eventhandler in office 365. so to upload solution through Sitesettings - Solutions we need to have Sandbox solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code compiles and runs fine for me as long as there is a reference to Microsoft.SharePoint (2010). Are you building a console application? In that case make sure you are using the .NET 3.5 framework (not compact or anything else) and set the platform target to Any CPU in the build section of the project properties.

BTW. note that you are leaking a site collection and a web object. You should looking at disposing both the SPSite and SPWeb instances.

Comment: I have written this code in Feature Receiver.

Comment: Its working fine for Farm Solution but I want it for Sandboxed Solution.

Comment: You cannot use the Add method or any of the overrides in a sandboxed solution. This is stated in the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms430598.aspx. You can only add event receivers declaratively here. See the comment on the referenced MSDN page.

Comment: Thanx Bernd,

I got solution which I was looking for.